# Appending large groups of elements in IE11 enormously slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, internet-explorer-11

I am encountering a massive problem in terms of loading big amounts of data into the DOM. In fact, only IE11 is the deal breaker here. Here is some example code first, basically I am doing this:

```
  var concat = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    concat[i] = "<li value='"+'XYZ' + i+"'>"+'XYZ ' + i+"</li>";
  }
  var element = conc.join('');
  $('ul.mylist').append(element);
```

Now, its broken down to a very basic example, its inspired by a jsFiddle I found here in a similar topic:

http://jsfiddle.net/bVAFF/152/

The fiddle works fine in IE!

I insert large chunks of list elements, up to ~10.000. This performs great since I am concatenating the single elements into one big string, which is appended to the DOM finally.

At least it performs great on Chrome and Firefox, it takes them 1-2 seconds to insert the data, whereas IE11 needs MINUTES to resurrect from its injection seizure.  I was experimenting with even bigger data amounts: strings with up to 9MB/70.000 Elements (!) still loaded "meh" (but i didnt test this on IE at that point).

I have to admit, that the strings I inject for real are way bigger than the ones in the (very simple) example, but still: it performs great on Chrome and FF. Only IE freezes!

Has anyone a clue why this is the case?

Greetings from Berlin!

Ahab

Comment: Welcome to Internet Explorer.

Comment: Well assuming IE performance aren't such great then you **must not** create so much elements. For sure user can't read them all together so you can build page step by step. Pagination? Infinite scroll? Up to you...

Comment: It does not look like your question can be reliably answered. At a minimum, the answerers would have to be deeply familiar with IE's internal workings. I don't know if such members exist in the community, and if they do, I'm not sure they'll be willing to  publicly document performance issues in their browser.

Comment: Does your overly simplified example that works in fiddle not work in your other environment? or did simplifying it make the problem go away.

Comment: @sWW well of course I'm not an IE fan but actually `.append()` is damn slow. If you remove it and you directly set inner HTML through `innerHtml` code performance will be decent also in IE. **Here problem isn't browser but code...**

Comment: @Adriano Repetti Well while the code might not be optimal, Chrome and Firefox seem to run it OK, so IE is clearly doing something unideal.

Comment: @sWW but code path for Chrome and IE isn't the same. jQuery may not have optimal algorithm to add raw HTML for IE (probably because no one  on Earth would add 70 MB HTML). That said, of course, Chrome performance are better (in average)

Answer (score 0):

setting aside jquery, which adds its own overhead, assigning to innerHTML is reasonably fast in IE-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>dynamic list</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
onload= function(){
    var start= new Date();
    var pa= document.querySelector('ul.mylist'), 
    timer= document.querySelector('h1'), 
    conc= [];
    for(var i= 0; i<10000; i++){
        conc[i]= '<li title= "XYZ' + i+'">XYZ ' + i+'</li>';
    }
    pa.innerHTML+= conc.join('\n');
    str= ' time: '+(new Date()-start)+' milliseconds'
    timer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>New list </h1>
<ul class="mylist">
<li title="First list item">First list item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

<!-- samples

IE 11: 130msec
Opera 22: 213 msec
FFox 31: 50msec
Chrome36: 125msec

-->
```

Comment: I found the solution and I have to admit, that I concealed a pretty important detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers so far, though they werent very helpful...

BUT I have to admit, I forgot an obviously very important detail in my post.

I am getting my list content (a lot of content) from a SOAP envelope, which contains a large JSON string I am parsing later.

However the parsing of the XML SOAP envelope was the operation that froze everything to death!

```
$(data).find('json_content').text();
```

That was the old operation. Now when doing a 'manual' XML traversal I can gain direct access to the JSON string:

```
var jsonString = 
data[0].documentElement.
childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Parsing the string, concatenating it, even pasting the content into DOM takes only seconds now. Its slower than in Chrome and Firefox, but now (finally!) I am talking about seconds. Not. Minutes.

I also testet innerHTML and compared it to jQuery.append().

innerHTMLwas hardly faster. :P

Greetz from B!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity

I've found that inserting the wrapper into the DOM first (before it has any children) sped it up from freezing the page to only taking 3 seconds

Initially I was creating a document fragment and appending that after it was properly populated (though that was best practice). Apparently that makes IE 11 choke if the fragment contains 10k children.

Comment: Hi @CheapSteaks, Could you please explain more details about this approach? I think I have a similar case with you right now. That would be a huge help, Thanks.